# Is there a way I can set for an email to be send as text with a Json code?

Tags: json

I have no JSON knowledge at all. I am using a ticketing system and need help to setup on below code that the ticket comments are also emailed to the user. I am adding on CC and that the email must be in plain text when received on the other end. Not sure if this is possible at all, but please if it is would greatly appreciate any help I can get.

```
{
    "request": {
        "email_ccs": [
            { "user_mail": "joeblog@myemail.com", "action": "put" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use images of text as they are not searchable (making your question less useful) and they are not accessible (reducing the number of people who could give you an answer). Please read  about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: JSON isn't sufficient scope for this question -- it's not a programming language (and can't, in and of itself, send email or do any other assertive step at all), it's just a data storage and interchange format.

Comment: ...now, can someone write a program that parses specific content out of a JSON file and sends email? Yes, absolutely, in almost any programming language you want! But that's too broad a question to be acceptable here -- you'll be in a better place if you pick a single, specific language; try to write such a program in it; and come back here and ask about a specific, narrow, well-defined problem you encountered while trying to make such an attempt.

Comment: Anyhow, you're presumably doing this while working somewhere that considers itself a Python shop, a Java shop, a Ruby shop, or otherwise a place where some specific language is typically used -- you'll be better-served using whatever language is conventional where you're at and familiar to your coworkers, rather than whatever a bunch of random people on the Internet see fit to use. :)

Comment: JSON is text. It is not code but configuration, at most. What is the software that uses that configuration? Without knowing this your question cannot be answered.